# how to implement newSingleThreadExecutor or newFixedThreadPool in my code

Tags: java, multithreading

I am hoping someone here can help me, I am quite new to using threading and what I need to do is put in a flag in my code to notify when all threads are done and then it invokes a method that updates the table to mark it as finished. I have read a lot about executor framework but I don't know how to implement it.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    LOG.info(args.length);

    LOG.info("Args = " + args);
    if (args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && args[0].equals("stop")) {
        stop(args);
    } else {
        new Thread(new PayatReconService()).start();
        LOG.info("This is after the main method");
    }
}

static void stop(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("STOPPING SERVER!");
    // Need to stop all TimerTasks here
    running = false;
    try {
        // sleep for a second, allow threads to close
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        LOG.info("exception " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    running = true;
    PayatReconService reconService = new PayatReconService();
    try {
        mailingQueue = new MailingQueue(prop);
        LOG.info("Starting Recon Service");
        ProcessRecon pr = new ProcessRecon();
        //Starts startRecon method in processRecon class
        pr.startRecon();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex, ex);
    }

  }
}
```

ProcessRecon.java:

```
  public void startRecon() throws SQLException {
    //log starting recon
    loadRetailers();
}




public void loadRetailers() throws SQLException {
DB db = new DB();
try (Connection con = db.getConnection(); PreparedStatement loadSt = con.prepareStatement(DB.LOAD_RETAILERS)){
       PayatReconService.LOG.info("Load Retailers");


        rs = loadSt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Retailer r = new Retailer();
           //Retrieve retailer information from company table
            r.setFtpFolder(rs.getString("ftp_folder"));
            r.setFtpPassword(rs.getString("ftp_password"));
            r.setFtpUsername(rs.getString("ftp_username"));
            r.setIsAutoRecon(rs.getBoolean("autorecon"));
            r.setIsSFTP(rs.getBoolean("sftp"));
            r.setReconFolder(rs.getString("reconfolder"));
            r.setRemoteFTPFolder(rs.getString("remoteftphost"));
            r.setRemoteFTPPassword(rs.getString("remoteftppassword"));
            r.setRemoteFTPUsername(rs.getString("remoteftpusername"));
            r.setReportPrefix(rs.getString("reportprefix"));
            r.setRetailID(rs.getString("recid"));
            r.setName(rs.getString("name"));


            new Thread(r).start();

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        PayatReconService.LOG.info(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

So on this class it retrieves all the information from the database and links it to a thread on the Retailer class, once all the information is retrieved it activates the run method.

Retailer.java:

```
  @Override
     public void run() {  
       try {

        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();           
        thread.setName(getName()); // Set thread name
    System.out.println("RunnableJob is being run by " + thread.getName() + " (" + thread.getId() + ")");
            PayatReconService.LOG.info("RunnableJob is being run by " + thread.getName() + " (" + thread.getId() + ")");

        DB db = new DB();
        try (Connection con = db.getConnection(); Statement st = con.createStatement()){

            while (PayatReconService.running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Retailer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                PayatReconService.LOG.info("Check if allowed to run");
                if (canRun()) {
                    PayatReconService.LOG.info("Run approved");
                    searchReconFile();
                   // the flag needs to be here to indicate that all the threads are done running
                    System.out.println("Mark table as complete");
                    markasComplete();   

                    PayatReconService.LOG.info("Waiting to rerun");
                    //wait 5min before trying again
                    Thread.sleep(300000);
                    PayatReconService.LOG.info("Go");                       
                } else {                        
                    Thread.sleep(300000);
                } 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //sql connect error
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            PayatReconService.LOG.info(e.getMessage());
            setErrors("01");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Retailer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

   }

  public void markasComplete() throws SQLException {
    PayatReconService.LOG.info("Update tblPay@Timers as complete.");
    DB db = new DB();
    try (Connection con = db.getConnection(); Statement st = con.createStatement()){

        String sql;
        sql = " update tblpay@timers set scheduled = 0 "
                + " where timertype in ('recon_new')";
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        PayatReconService.LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

So before markasComplete() can run, all the threads should first finish and then update the table, if someone could please help me that would be great or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways - probably the best is to use a latch, for example this code starts 10 tasks and a separate one which runs when they've all finished:

```
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int threadId = i;
        Callable<?> c = new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                long waitUntil = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() + (Math.random() * 5000));
                while(System.currentTimeMillis() < waitUntil);
                latch.countDown();
                System.out.println("Finished task " + threadId);
                return null;
            }
        };
        service.submit(c);
    }

    // Start a thread which will run when the others are finished.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try { latch.await(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            System.out.println("All finished");
        }
    }).start();

    // Carry on main thread....
    Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

Of course, you could just shutdown the executor service and wait until it finishes, in which case you don't need a latch, by replacing the last thread with:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            service.shutdown();
            try { service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.DAYS); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            System.out.println("All finished");
        }
    }).start();
```